# Is it possible fight against domainers?

Tags: domains

these days I have looking for a domain for my web application, but I've realized that the 99% of them are bought and of these the 9/10 are from domainer speculators.

"Welcome to the real world" maybe you think, but I'm wondering if there is anything that we can do to "fight" against this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do anything. As the internet is free, anyone has the right to purchase whatever domains they need and not be asked why. If you're looking for a domain name for your web application, I suggest you to think of something nobody has thought of before.

If the domain name is registered, then your original name is not original. Think of another one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are ways, none of them legal, though. 
What you can do is not care so much about it and think of something else, be creative. 
Google and Drupal are names that came up due to misspellings and are quite successful.

Answer (score 0):

Yea you just have to be creative. Also check other domain extensions like .me or .co which are becoming more popular.

Say you're web app is about food - try domains like foodzen.com or foodniche.com, etc, etc.